# I have this image I want to get contour of apple and reference object

Tags: python, opencv

[This original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH5eq.jpg)

after run this code i have this image [After threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaCFs.png)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_f = cv2.medianBlur( gray, 5)
img_t = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_f,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,21,2)

I want to get the contour of apple and the square box.
Can any one help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: why don't you use cv2.findContours to find contours if you've never tried it!

Comment: I did it but It got a lot of contours so I didn't get the right contours. I filtered and sorted the contour but couldn't